# Excecption upon start of tomcat server with spring application

Tags: java, spring

All of a sudden started to get following  error upon starting the server.
Switched from java 1.8 to java 1.7 but no luck...

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mobileFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mobileFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'daoAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/security-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'personClientFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mobileFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mobileFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'daoAuthenticationProvider' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/security-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userDetailsService' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/security-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'personClientFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: can you paste your security-context.xml

Comment: can't help you, too little information

Comment: Issue might be in your **userDetailsService** bean definition while injecting properties in it.
It will be better if you share your /WEB-INF/classes/security-context.xml file.

Comment: Solved : Mistake from my side, I was referring to old configuration file in tomcat server which is related to all the properties of the application. It was a miss on my side and hence the issue.